# Rollback in single stored procedure for forloop & insert query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollback

I am new to rollback. I have six insert queries. I am executing all six queries after a button click.

But out of the six queries, two of the insert queries are in the for loop (in for loop I am iterating trough the repeater).

If any of the insert query giving exception then I want to do the rollback if all the insert queries are successfully executed then only I have to commit all of them.

Here's is my code:

```
string InsertInventory = "insert into RS_Inventory_Master (product_name,category_id,quick_overview,description,image,isactive,product_code,barcode, inventory_group_id,entry_date,update_date) values ('" + ProductName + "','" + category_ddl.SelectedValue + "','" + Quick_Overview + "','" + Desc + "','" + inventory_img + "','" + active + "','" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + barcode_name + "', '" + brand_ddl.SelectedValue + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')";
cm.TableInsert(insertInventory);

string query = "insert into RS_Inventory_buying_master (product_code,buying_price,isactive,date,latest) values('" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + BuyingPrice + "','1','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','1')";
cm.TableInsert(query);

string qry = "insert into RS_Inventory_Selling_Master (product_code,selling_price,isactive,date,latest) values('" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + SellingPrice + "','1','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','1')";
cm.TableInsert(qry);

//string WeightU = weight_txt.Text.Replace(".", "");
string InsertWeight = "insert into RS_Inventory_Weight_Master (product_code,weight,latest,date,isactive,unit_id) values('" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + ProductWeight + "','1','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','1','" + unit_ddl.SelectedValue + "')";
cm.TableInsert(InsertWeight);

for (int j = 0; j < rpt_sup_lst.Items.Count; j++)
{
    CheckBox ck = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("vendor_ck") as CheckBox;
    HiddenField vendor_id = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("h_vendor_id") as HiddenField;
    HiddenField vendor_code = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("h_vendor_code") as HiddenField;

    if (ck.Checked == true)
    {
       string v_id = vendor_id.Value;
       string vc_id = vendor_code.Value;
       string insertVendor = "insert into RS_Inventory_Vendor_Mapping (vendor_id,product_code,vendor_code) values ('" + v_id + "','" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + vc_id + "')";
       cm.TableInsert(insertVendor);
    }
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < rpt_tax_lst.Items.Count; i++)
 {
     CheckBox ck = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("tax_chk") as CheckBox;
     HiddenField tax_id = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("h_tax_id") as HiddenField;
     HiddenField tax_code = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("h_taxcde_id") as HiddenField;

     if (ck.Checked == true)
     {
         string t_id = tax_id.Value;
         string tc_id = tax_code.Value;

         string insertTax = "insert into RS_Inventory_Tax_Mapping (tax_id,product_code,tax_code) values ('" + t_id + "','" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + tc_id + "')";
         cm.TableInsert(insertTax);
      }
  }
```

How to achieve rollback for this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: start a transaction before the insert and have try catch exception on failure rollback transaction

Comment: To be able to `ROLLBACK` you need to encapsulate the statements that make up a transaction in [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) and `END TRANSACTION` then you can call either `COMMIT TRANSACTION` to actually make it happen and end the transaction or you call `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` to reverse all the transaction

Comment: Yes. thank you Sir. but how can I achieve the same for forloop

Comment: you should just start the transaction before the loop and end it after that

Comment: Can you please show me how to achieve this. I am new to rollback

Comment: @Hardik - what is so hard about moving the transction create outside of a loop? That is not "new to rollback" it is "I have no clue what programming is" if you do not know how to move an instruction outside of a loop.

Comment: instead of writing code that is prone to SQL Injection, you need to call SQL Stored Procedure that is handling transactions.

Comment: Yes that is the main problem. that I have to write only single stored procedure for all the six queries. & also if suppose for loop is iterating six times then how can I get all the six rows or all values that are in the forloop to Sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution 
how to achieve rollback within one query.

**Code behind(Asp .Net)**

```
DataTable dt_vendor = new DataTable();
dt_vendor.Columns.Add("Vendor_id", typeof(int));
dt_vendor.Columns.Add("Product_code", typeof(string));
dt_vendor.Columns.Add("Vendor_code", typeof(string));


for (int j = 0; j < rpt_sup_lst.Items.Count; j++)
{

    CheckBox ck = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("vendor_ck") as CheckBox;
    HiddenField vendor_id = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("h_vendor_id") as HiddenField;
    HiddenField vendor_code = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("h_vendor_code") as HiddenField;

    if (ck.Checked == true)
    {
        string v_id = vendor_id.Value;
        string vc_id = vendor_code.Value;
        dt_vendor.Rows.Add(v_id, productcde_txt.Text, vc_id);
        //string insertVendor = "insert into RS_Inventory_Vendor_Mapping (vendor_id,product_code,vendor_code) values ('" + v_id + "','" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + vc_id + "')";
        //cm.TableInsert(insertVendor);
    }
}
DataTable dt_tax = new DataTable();
dt_tax.Columns.Add("Tax_id", typeof(int));
dt_tax.Columns.Add("Product_code", typeof(string));
dt_tax.Columns.Add("Tax_code", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < rpt_tax_lst.Items.Count; i++)
{

    CheckBox ck = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("tax_chk") as CheckBox;
    HiddenField tax_id = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("h_tax_id") as HiddenField;
    HiddenField tax_code = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("h_taxcde_id") as HiddenField;

    if (ck.Checked == true)
    {
        string t_id = tax_id.Value;
        string tc_id = tax_code.Value;

        dt_tax.Rows.Add(t_id, productcde_txt.Text, tc_id);
        //string insertTax = "insert into RS_Inventory_Tax_Mapping (tax_id,product_code,tax_code) values ('" + t_id + "','" + productcde_txt.Text + "','" + tc_id + "')";
        //cm.TableInsert(insertTax);
    }
}

string  strasd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strasd);
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsert_Add_Inventory", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//Pass table Valued parameter to Store Procedure
SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp_vendor", dt_vendor);
sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp_tax", dt_tax);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", productname_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", category_ddl.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quick_overview", quick_review_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", desc_txt.Content);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", inventory_img);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isactive", act_chk.Checked);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_code", productcde_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buying_price", buy_prce_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selling_price", sell_prce_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_weight", weight_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit_id", unit_ddl.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inventory_group_id", brand_ddl.SelectedValue);

sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;                
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TYPE Inventory_Tax_Mapping_Type AS TABLE 
(   
  Tax_id  int,
  Product_code VARCHAR(500),
  Tax_code VARCHAR(500)
);
GO


CREATE TYPE Inventory_Vendor_Mapping_Type AS TABLE 
(   
  Vendor_id  int,
  Product_code VARCHAR(500),
  Vendor_code VARCHAR(500)
);
GO




ALTER PROC spInsert_Add_Inventory
(
    @product_name VARCHAR(100),
    @category_id int,
    @quick_overview VARCHAR(5000),
    @description ntext,
    @image VARCHAR(20),
    @isactive bit,  
    @product_code VARCHAR(20),
    @barcode VARCHAR(20),
    @buying_price float,
    @selling_price float,
    @product_weight float,
    @unit_id int,
    @inventory_group_id int,    
    @tvp_tax Inventory_Tax_Mapping_Type READONLY,
    @tvp_vendor Inventory_Vendor_Mapping_Type READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

            --Logic for Inserting Inventory Master
            INSERT INTO RS_Inventory_Master 
            (product_name,category_id,quick_overview,[description],[image],isactive,product_code,barcode, inventory_group_id,entry_date,update_date) 
            VALUES
            (@product_name,@category_id,@quick_overview,@description,@image,@isactive,@product_code,@barcode,@inventory_group_id,GETDATE(),GETDATE())


            --Logic for Inserting Inventory Buying Master
            INSERT INTO RS_Inventory_buying_master 
            (product_code,buying_price,isactive,date,latest) 
            VALUES
            (@product_code,@buying_price,1,GETDATE(),1)

            --Logic For Selling Price
            INSERT INTO RS_Inventory_Selling_Master 
            (product_code,selling_price,isactive,date,latest) 
            values(@product_code,@selling_price,1,GETDATE(),1)

            --Logic for Inserting Product Weight
            INSERT INTO RS_Inventory_Weight_Master 
            (product_code,weight,latest,date,isactive,unit_id) 
            VALUES
            (@product_code,@product_weight,1,GETDATE(),1,@unit_id)


            --Logic For Inserting Tax values.
            --@tvp_tax is the Table valued parmameter In this parameter we are pasing whole table ie Whole forloop
            INSERT INTO RS_Inventory_Tax_Mapping            
            SELECT Product_code,Tax_id,Tax_code
            FROM @tvp_tax

            --Logic For Inserting Vendor values
            INSERT INTO RS_Inventory_Vendor_Mapping
            SELECT Product_code,Vendor_id,Vendor_code
            FROM @tvp_vendor

            COMMIT

    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH 

              DECLARE @ERROR_MSG NVARCHAR(MAX), @SEVERITY INT, @STATE INT
              SELECT @SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @STATE = ERROR_STATE()
              , @ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' err src line: ' + CAST( ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '');           
               --@ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()
                ROLLBACK;
             -- RE-THROW EXCEPTION FOR DIAGNOSTIC VISIBILITY
              RAISERROR (@ERROR_MSG ,@SEVERITY, @STATE);        
              RETURN

    END CATCH   

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to pass the values all to a SQL stored procedure and let it handle all the values within a Transaction block. you can do the same thing in code but this is an example of the step with a table type

--IN SQL

```
CREATE TYPE Inventory_Tax_MappingType AS TABLE 
( Tax_id as VARCHAR(20),
  Product_code as VARCHAR(20),
  Tax_code as VARCHAR(20));
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. usp_InsertInventory_Tax_Mapping
    @TVP Inventory_Tax_MappingType READONLY
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO RS_Inventory_Tax_Mapping
        SELECT Tax_id, Product_code, Tax_code
        FROM  @TVP;
        COMMIT 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
GO

-- IN C# 
DataTable myTable =  new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Tax_id", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Product_code", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Tax_code", typeof(string));

for (int j = 0; j < rpt_sup_lst.Items.Count; j++)
{
    CheckBox ck = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("vendor_ck") as CheckBox;
    HiddenField vendor_id = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("h_vendor_id") as HiddenField;
    HiddenField vendor_code = rpt_sup_lst.Items[j].FindControl("h_vendor_code") as HiddenField;

    if (ck.Checked == true)
    {
       string v_id = vendor_id.Value;
       string vc_id = vendor_code.Value;
       myTable.Rows.Add(v_id, productcde_txt.Text, vc_id );
    }
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < rpt_tax_lst.Items.Count; i++)
 {
     CheckBox ck = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("tax_chk") as CheckBox;
     HiddenField tax_id = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("h_tax_id") as HiddenField;
     HiddenField tax_code = rpt_tax_lst.Items[i].FindControl("h_taxcde_id") as HiddenField;

     if (ck.Checked == true)
     {
         string t_id = tax_id.Value;
         string tc_id = tax_code.Value;
         myTable.Rows.Add(t_id, productcde_txt.Text, tc_id );
      }
  }

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("***");
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertValue", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//Pass table Valued parameter to Store Procedure
SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @TVP", myTable);
sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

NOT TESTED, but you get the point.

Comment: Means for each for loop I need to create seperate stored procedure am i right?

Comment: You have to call the stored procedure (execute it) in each loop